# Jquery doesn't take the val()

Tags: jquery

I have a little problem with the jQuery - In jquery ui confirm dialog i have 2 inputs:
first - hidden with precise value=""
second - input text - and here is the problem.

When I click "ok" the script sending me only first value, second is empty. But when I write the value="123" there two are sending.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="MyIn" id="MyIn" name="MyIn" >
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$r['order_id'];?>" class="orderid" id="orderid" >
```

JavaScript:

```
  $("a.opener").click(function (e) {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog({

            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    var sendNumber = $("input#MyIn").val();
                    var orderid = $("input#orderid").val();

                    var dataString = 'orderid=' + orderid + '&sendNumber=' + sendNumber;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "moduls/send.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function () {
                            $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
                        }
                    });
                    return false;

                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This will leak memory in IE. Create the dialog once on page load or first use, then reopen / close it on link clicks.

Comment: do you mean to say that in send.php, the value of $_POST['orderid'] is null? or is it just blank?

Comment: The input#MyIn is null - I see in the Firebug that Post Parameters of sendNumber is null.

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't make much difference but it can be good practice, when sending data through AJAX, to include a DATATYPE, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "moduls/send.php",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function () {
    $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
  }
});
```

Comment: Because without it, people like you forget to put it in :) If you get used to using it all the time, you won't.

Comment: I forgot because I never ever use $.ajax I generally use $.post $.get $.getJSON ect. For which datatype is seldom needed.

Answer (score 1):

I very much suspect that `<?=$r['order_id'];?>` is returning an empty string. If this is the case it will not be sent through. Also dataString is not the preferred way of handing params in jQuery. Bellow is with a catch for this scenario:

```
$("a.opener").click(function (e) {
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({

        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {

                // if sendNumber fails or evaluates to false, 
                // it will be replaced with 'null', insuring its sent anyway
                // and you can trap on the serverside.
                var sendNumber = $("input#MyIn").val() || 'null';
                var orderid = $("input#orderid").val();

                var postData = { orderid : orderid, sendNumber : sendNumber};

                //shorthand of extra niceness
                $.post('moduls/send.php', postData, function(){
                     $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
                });
                return false;

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Think you need **DATATYPE: JSON;** in there don't you. Without that line, it defaults as TEXT.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid you are right, I am just so used to the shorthand. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I make your code and the answer is:
The input#MyIn is null - I see in the Firebug that Post Parameters of sendNumber is null.

Comment: then it IS sending through, its sending through 'null' because that field does not have a valid value. What would you like it to send through?

Comment: But when i write in html value="123" the script sending 123 :) if i don't write antyhing, he sending null because I used it code :))

Comment: So its true then `<?=$r['order_id'];?>` is an empty string. Do you want it to send an empty string?

Comment: The problem is not <input type="hidden" value="<?=$r['order_id'];?>" class="orderid" id="orderid" >

The problem is in: <input type="text" value="" class="MyIn" id="MyIn" name="MyIn" >

Comment: So you would like 'orderid' to pass an empty string?

Comment: No, no, no :P

Pls. watch the video i show what is wrong:
http://www30.zippyshare.com/v/29703732/file.html

Comment: Ok, I konow where is the problem, but i don't knwo how to fix it. 

if I take: <input type="text" value="" class="MyIn" id="MyIn" name="MyIn" > out of dialog - working ideal. In dialog dont sending anything.

Comment: Ok that is weird. Can I see your full html?

Answer (score 0):

Your current jQuery code should be working as the refence of the hidden input element's value is valid.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3qpV4/

Try alerting the value to ensure it is being set properly.  If it isn't, then you know that the problem is in your PHP variable expansion.  If it does alert, then the issue is with your PHP file `send.php`.

Comment: The send.php is a not problem.
The input#MyIn is null - I see in the Firebug that Post Parameters of sendNumber is null.

Comment: Do you have a value in that input element when you are trying to pass it?

Comment: Pls. watch the video i show what is wrong:
http://www30.zippyshare.com/v/29703732/file.html